# Selecting children MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, children

After I figured out how to get the parents, I want to get the childs, 
but I can't figure it out..

My tables:

```
nvc_blog
    blogID
    Title
    Content

nvc_blog_cat
    catID
    parentID
    catSafe

nvc_blog_catmap
    id
    blogID
    catID
```

I am able to get the blog posts from the selected category (fotografie)
But how can I get the blog posts from the children categories?
`JOIN nvc_blog_cat AS child1 ON child1.parentID = parent.catID` doesn't work :/

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`nvc_blog`)
JOIN `nvc_blog_catmap` AS map ON `map`.`blogID` = `nvc_blog`.`blogID`
JOIN `nvc_blog_cat` AS parent ON `parent`.`catID` = `map`.`catID`

WHERE `parent`.`catSafe` =  'fotografie'
```

Comment: Are you providing all your table definitions? Your SELECT statement tables and columns do not match the structure you provided.

Comment: Sorry, some mistypes, now it should be good (catSafe = catName)

Answer (score 0):

If you use categories/subcategories/subsubcategories... then you have to change the logic for inserting entries in nvc_blog_catmap.

First of all your initial insert must have the last category level. Then while a category has a parent that is different from its id (or 0 - indicating there is no parent) you have to insert another record to nvc_blog_catmap using the parent as your catID.

This approach will allow you to avoid involving nested categories in select queries.